# Other Centrailty Measures in the Boost Graph Libary

Tags: c++, graph-theory, boost-graph

I was wondering if any one else knows of other ways to measure the importance of certain nodes in a graph in general and in the boost graph library.

These are the ones I already have.

- Degree centrality
- closeness centrality
- mean path length
- clustering coefficient

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other measures of [Centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality). The most obvious ones you are missing are Betweenness and Eigenvector centrality which are explained on the Wiki page.

Boost does [Betweenness](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/graph/doc/betweenness_centrality.html) but not Eigenvector centrality. You may have to convert the graph to a matrix and use something like [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html) which is also header only.

Comment: Ok, beside toughs, I added them recently to my project, I know there's k-page,page rank, katz, and shannon-perry, are there any other standard ones?

Comment: I have heard of page rank, but none of the others you mention. You may know more than the rest of us. I would search google scholar for a centrality review paper. I would also test the correlation between your measures. They will likely be highly correlated (many of the complicated ones anyway). It will all depend on your needs. Look for review papers.

Comment: This paper may give you some clues [Using Graph Theory to Analyze Biological Networks](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1756-0381-4-10.pdf)